# Does "was fuer" take the accusative?

Tags: accusative

Which of the following is correct?

"Was fuer ein kleiner Teufel bist du?"

```
           or
```

"Was fuer einen kleinen Teufel bist du?"

Comment: Lots of questions with the same answer recently. There's the copula *sein* in there (*bist*), the piece *ein kleiner Teufel* is a *Prädikativ*, a "nominative object".